# p:poll not starting immediately

Tags: jsf, primefaces, polling

Hi I am really a newbie to Jsf and Primefaces world,I have a simple query regarding primefaces poll component which is as follows.

I have a login page,once the user is authenticated i redirect him to welcome.xhtml page where i have to poll a database service every 2mins, i have used primefaces polling component for this
`<p:poll interval="120" listener="#{databaseService.getJob}"/>` it works fine and polls after every 2mins but what i want is that once the user is authenticated and lands to welcome page the polling service should start immediately rather than waiting for the timeInterval of 2mins. To achieve this i tried using the `autoStart="true"`

```
<p:poll interval="120" listener="#{databaseService.getJob}" autoStart="true" />
```

but it didnt work.

So let me know how do i achieve this.

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your method to be called immediately use RemoteCommand with autoRun="true", dont use your poll component's autoStart feature and when oncomplete of RemoteCommand is triggered start your poll manually like this (untested):

```
<p:poll id="databaseServicePoll" interval="120" listener="#{databaseService.getJob}" autoStart="false" />

<p:remoteCommand name="firstDatabaseServiceCall" actionListener="#{databaseService.getJob}"
autoRun="true" oncomplete="databaseServicePoll.start()" />
```

Comment: But why? If `autoRun` is a default option and TS just using it wrong, he should learn a proper way to do that, not some weird workaround

Comment: the default behaviour of poll component is to do first polling after the interval set, autoRun just specifies if this should start automatically or manually. this is convenient since the component assumes that you already loaded the initial data on your page load, so the next poll should start after a while. What I suggest is to do the first call using the remoteCommand and then start the poll so the next call will be scheduled. Its not a weird workaround, its a way to solve the current problem.

Comment: This answer should be accepted. OP should have done this and upvoted. @ozantabak: please add the comment to the answer, it is good addition